# To update dictionary in Angular

Tags: angular8

```
export class AdduserComponent implements OnInit {
dict = {}
onsubmit(form:Form){
this.http.post(this.url, JSON.stringify(post_data)).subscribe( response => {
 console.log(response);
 if(response['Successful']){
      this.dict["data"] = object.keys(response['successful'])[0]
      this.router.navigate(['/users'])
  }
}
}
```

Here, I have declared empty dict and want to update the dict after when I got response from api.

Comment: Can you post what your response object looks like and the what information you are trying to extract.

Comment: Explain a bit more what you want to achieve ?

Answer (score 0):

Your `dict` object will be updated from your code but if your are using into another component then you have to store either in localstorage or somewhere else in browser. Thank you :)

Answer (score -1):

```
export class AdduserComponent implements OnInit {
dict = {}
onsubmit(form:Form){
let self = this
this.http.post(this.url, JSON.stringify(post_data)).subscribe( response => {
 console.log(response);
 if(response['Successful']){
      self.dict["data"] = object.keys(response['successful'])[0]
      this.router.navigate(['/users'])
  }
}
}
```